# How to properly return a string from a method with try and catch

Tags: java, android, facebook, parsing

Every time I called this method it always return null even if the value of userProfile.get("facebookId") is not null.

```
public String updateProfilePicture() {

    String facebookId = null;

    if (currentUser.get("profile") != null) {
        JSONObject userProfile = currentUser.getJSONObject("profile");
        try {
            if (userProfile.getString("facebookId") != null) {

                facebookId = userProfile.get("facebookId").toString();

            } else {

                facebookId = null;

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // handle error
            facebookId = null;
        }
    }


    return facebookId;
}
```

Comment: log it and post the logcat please

Comment: Are you sure ? Try to debug the application & see the value in facebookId

Comment: looks good (from the return perspective). Are you sure that the json contains that key ?

Comment: Looks ok to me too... But why are you mixing `userProfile.getString("facebookId")` and `userProfile.get("facebookId").toString()`? But at the first glance, this shouldn't be a problem either... We would need more info to look into it.

Comment: Log the exception in the catch block to make sure there is no JSONException thrown.

Comment: Add log in catch block and see whether it is caught or not. As you have said userProfile.get("facebookId") is not null then most probably there is possibility of throwing JSONException.

Comment: it's fine now, sorry I forgot I just used different emulator.